# Make sure the string contains only int or float

Tags: ruby, regex

How can I write a REGEX in Ruby to make sure that the string is only and integer. For example

```
3 --> Returns true
3g --> Returns False
4.3 --> Returns False
```

Similarly, how can i write a REGEX to make sure it's float?
For example

```
3 --> Returns False
3g --> Returns False
4.3 --> Returns True
```

I need REGEX for both int and float. I thought for int it is just /\d+/ and /\d+.\d+/ for float but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
str = "111"
if(str =~ /^\d+$/)
    print "matched\n";
end

str = "4.3"
if(str =~ /^\d+\.\d+$/)
    print "matched\n";
end
```

Comment: That was easy. Thank you. :)

Comment: What about `'-3.1415927'` or `'-11'`?

Comment: Also, `'3'` is a valid float as well.

Answer (score 3):

A regex isn't the best solution to this problem. The easiest way to cover all the possibilities is to use [`Kernel#Float`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-Float) to try to convert the string to a `Float` and then catch the exception:

```
def float?(str)
  !!Float(str)
rescue ArgumentError
  false
end
```

That will cover leading signs (`'+2.18'`, `-3.14`), ignore leading and trailing whitespace, and even handle scientific notation for floats. One hole in just using `Kernel#Float` is that it won't understand `'NaN'` as a `Float` even though `Float::NAN.to_s == 'NaN'` is true, if you want to consider `'NaN'` to be a `Float` then you could do something like this:

```
def float?(str)
  str.strip == 'NaN' || !!Float(str)
rescue ArgumentError
  false
end
```

Similarly for `Float::INFINITY`/`'Infinity'` and `-Float::INFINITY`/`'-Infinity'`.

There's also [`Kernel#Integer`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer) if you want to check integers separately.

Comment: This is the most robust solution.

Answer (score 1):

You want a single regex that matches both integers and floats?

```
/\A[-+]?\d+(\.\d+)?\z/
```

This matches a series of digits (at least one), optionally followed by a dot and another series of digits.

Comment: What about `'-3.1415927'` or `'-11'`?

Comment: @muistooshort you're right. I updated the regex so it also matches if the number is preceded with a minus sign.

Comment: I'd probably go with `[-+]?`, `\A` instead of `^`, and `\z` instead of `$`. Using `^` and `$` can have surprising behavior when the string contains newlines.

Comment: Right again :) I did consider `[-+]?` before, but the OP was not too clear about what should and should not match. And newlines in the string should cause validation to fail, so `\A` and `\z` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Check if it is integer:

```
"3" !~ /\D/
"3g" !~ /\D/
"4.3" !~ /\D/
```

Check if it is float:

```
!!("3" =~ /\A\d+\.\d+\z/)
!!("3g" =~ /\A\d+\.\d+\z/)
!!("4.3" =~ /\A\d+\.\d+\z/)
```

Comment: What about `'-3.1415927'` or `'-11'`?

Comment: @muistooshort That needs to be considered, but the OP had a regex that suggests that negative values do not need to be considered. And I assumed that. You are right. But the OP was not clear.